# Django REST Framework. How do I create two identical tags with different values?

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Another **Django REST Framework** problem that I don't understand how to solve?
There are two objects **image_1** and **image_2**.

In **serializers.py**:

```
class someClass(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image_1 = serializers.ImageField(source='image_1')
    image_2 = serializers.ImageField(source='image_2')
    class Meta:
        model = onlyimage
        fields = ['image_1', 'image_2']
```

In the output, I get:

```
<image_1>https://domain-name.com/media/image_1</image_1>
<image_2>https://domain-name.com/media/image_2</image_2>
```

I want the  tag not to be numbered like in the example below:

```
<image>https://domain-name.com/media/image_1</image>
<image>https://domain-name.com/media/image_2</image>
```

But if you change in **serializers.py**, of course, an error occurs:

```
class someClass(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    image = serializers.ImageField(source='image_1')
    image = serializers.ImageField(source='image_2')
    class Meta:
        model = onlyimage
        fields = ['image', 'image']
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears you are trying to use a serializer to generate HTML, so the short answer is you can't use serialization in that way.

The [documentation](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/) says:

> Serializers allow complex data such as querysets and model instances
> to be converted to native Python datatypes that can then be easily
> rendered into JSON, XML or other content types.

Although it says "... or other content types." the use of serialization is to convert your model in to a simple data stream for transmission and then, importantly, **deserialization**.

By definition fields in a model must be unique. If your serialized model has two fields both called `<image>` the deserialization process will not know which bit of you data to put where.

Without more information on what you are *actually* trying to do with your model it's hard to suggest another way.

Comment: Hello! Thanks for your reply. I have a catalog site, I am preparing an XML file to transfer catalog objects to specialized message boards. To send all images of an object, they must be in the same <image> tags, I depicted this in the example. Yes, I know there must be different tags. The question is how to make it so that the output is <image_1>, <image_2>, etc. took the form <image>

Comment: @I.Z. - have you tried storing the images in a list and serializing that? Take a look at using the [ListsSrializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer) and if necessary you can [customise its behaviour](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#customizing-listserializer-behavior).